# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in zk zkoss

Tags: java, servlet-filters, zk

I got this strange error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException":

While there is No array used in code!
Any idea about this error?
Is it a bug in catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain library! or problem in my code?

```
    STACKTRACE:
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
    at event.ColSizeEvent.<init>(ColSizeEvent.java)
    at ColSizeEvent.getColSizeEvent(ColSizeEvent.java)
```

Comment: can you post stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I did add stack trace.

Comment: does it work if you remove the doFIlter ?

Comment: Yes it was work before filter

Comment: Any update or help?

Comment: We are using zk EE and make good use of their ticketing system: https://potix.freshdesk.com. If you are not an enterprise customer, you can still try to report the issue to http://tracker.zkoss.org or http://forum.zkoss.org. It usually helps if you can boil the issue down to a minimal example, e.g. on http://zkfiddle.org/. In that case update your question, and maybe we can help you already.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your exception is not related to the `filterChain.doFilter(...)` code itself.

That line simply routes the HTTP request to zkoss, which tries to create some elements, and fails there.

```
    at org.zkoss.zul.event.ColSizeEvent.<init>(ColSizeEvent.java:124)
        at org.zkoss.zul.event.ColSizeEvent.getColSizeEvent(ColSizeEvent.java:69)
        at org.zkoss.zul.impl.HeadersElement.service(HeadersElement.java:75)
   ...
```

Check (or share) your zkoss conf...

Comment: ColSizeEvent and HeadersElement are jar files (third library) :
https://www.zkoss.org

Comment: I know, it's a framework for creating UI. Seems your bug is there, when your service is accessed, the UI is created by zkoss.  Try adding the "zk" tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

The exact thing that is out of bounds is `ColSizeEvent` in ColSizeEvent.java:124 when it tries to getColSizeEvent() from out of bounds area.

If that's the 3d party library it contains the bug and you need to go to that line and fix or post the whole source.(jar is also an archive there are tools to get it out). If you can't get the source then, we are out of luck(but you probably can). In any way you would need to rebuild zkoss.

Always go from the first trace line down - it tells you exactly where the Exception was raised, and how it's propagated.